# Takes function and throws exception if passed function doesn't throw an exception

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, error-handling

The code below is part of a toy test assertion library I've written.

I'm looking for feedback specifically on lines 4 - 9.  I'd like to extract them from the `throws` function.  I can think of two options.

1. Create a function with a name like `maybeReportExceptionError()`.  This seems not great because a) it feels like the function has two responsibilities and b) the `maybe` in the name seems hard to understand for someone not familiar with the inner workings of the function.
2. Replace the if/else if with a polymorphism.  I'm not sure how to go about this.

Any thoughts greatly appreciated!

```js
function throws(testFunction, expectedMessage) {
  var thrownMessage = getFunctionExceptionMessage(testFunction);

  if (thrownMessage === undefined) {
    throw new Error("Expected an exception");
  } else if (thrownMessage !== expectedMessage) {
    throw new Error("Threw - " + thrownMessage + " - not - " + expectedMessage);
  }
};

function getFunctionExceptionMessage(fn) {
  try {
    fn();
  } catch (exception) {
    return exception.message;
  }
};

// USAGE:

// Throws "Error: Expected an exception"
throws(function() {

}, "Expected message");

// Throws "Error: Threw - Thrown message - not - Expected message"
throws(function() {
  throw new Error("Thrown message");
}, "Expected message");
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It kind of boils down to coding style, but this is how I'd refactor your code.

1. I like my assertions to clearly state they are; rename `throws()` to `assertThrows()`.
2. I like guard clauses rather than "unneccessary" `else` statements.
3. If a function ever throws an exception with an undefined message, your assertion would fail.
4. I like a specific format of assert failures: expected xxx but got yyy.

Code:

```
function assertThrows(testFunction, expectedMessage) {

    var actual = catchExceptionFrom(testFunction); 

    if (actual === undefined)
        throw new Error("Function did not throw an exception.");

    if (actual.message !== expectedMessage)
        throw new Error("Expected exception '" + expectedMessage + "' but got '" + actual.message + "'");
}; 

function catchExceptionFrom(fn) { 
    try { 
        fn(); 
    } 
    catch (exception) { 
        return exception; 
    } 
};
```

Comment: This is really helpful.  All your refactors make sense.  Thank you!